# How big should my javascript files be for minifying it to make a difference?

Tags: javascript, minify, bundling-and-minification

I know minifying my javascript files can speed up delivery and performance. However, for small files, this is not noticeable. At what point does minifying it really have an impact?

Comment: Why not minify anyway? What does it cost? The improvement would only be for the first request, thereafter the browser would use a cached copy.

Comment: very subjective. depends on your server, hit rate and all

Comment: about as big as a string is long

Comment: If you're worrying about knowing when to minify, you're prematurely optimising. Until it begins to noticeably hit performance - your pages take too long to load, for instance - it's not a pressing issue.

Comment: A good byte is a byte never sent by the server. You should always optimize your statics because even if you feel your application is fast without minification, maybe a network latency for some users would be balanced by a minified code. Note that minification is certainly not the first optimization to perform, put priority on gzip.